# TortoiseSVN backup and restore

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, backup

I need to backup repository in TortoiseSVN and move it to a new PC. What are the steps to do create the back up?

I can't find backup option in the menu, the only thing I found was the command-line way:

```
svnadmin dump C:\SVN\MyProject > C:\tmp\MyProject.bak
```

I am assuming that C:\SVN\MyProject is the repository directory? If so, I don't know where mine is located and don't know how to find out (no indication is given in the menu at all).

If someone knows how to backup and restore a repository using clear steps that would be great!

**EDITED:**
My SVN is served with file system

```
file:///D:/svn/myproject
```

`svnadmin` command doesn't work

The easiest and simplest way is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you access you repository through *svn://* protocol then it means it's served by the *svnserve* service.

Try to look up that service in the services manager and see the command line used to start it. That command line contains the path to the repository directory on disk. That's the directory you want to back up.

Command line options for *svnserve* are documented [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnserve.html#svn.ref.svnserve.sw). You're interested in the *root* option.

If your repository is served by *Apache* (*http://* protocol) then you can find out the repository path in the Apache configuration files, as described [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic). Look for *SVNPath*.

Usually you can just copy the given repository directory to a new PC and point *svnserve* or *Apache* to that new directory.

This may not work due to differences in svn versions. Thus you may want to go with *dump* / *load* approach documented [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate).

It's pretty straightforward:

```
svnadmin dump C:\SVN\MyProject > dumpfile
# copy the dumpfile to a new PC
svnadmin load C:\SVN\MyNewProject < dumpfile
```

Comment: svnadmin is not recognized..is there a way to do it without it? or should I forget about the repository...actually after spending 2+ hours on this, I am kind of ready to.

Comment: You can do it without svnadmin - just copy the whole folder. Did you find a repository folder already?

Comment: thinking about your question again - do you actually want to move the repository from one server to the other? or just move the files you work with to another PC?

Comment: I want to re-create my set-up on a new PC. Files will be moved, so all I want to do is move the repository too....I found the repository folder..but how do I move the repository? Just move the folder that contains the repository?

Comment: Well, i think everyone thought you want to move repository between servers. What you want to do is to move working copy. It should be ok to just copy the folder with your files - everything svn related is in the hidden '.svn' subfolders. Or just leave it and checkout from the repository on a new PC. (repository is on the server, working copy is on your PC)

Comment: And yes - to move the repository you can move the folder that contains it. Then point svnserve on a new PC to that folder.

Comment: Thanks. i will clarify. I don't have a server - I am using Tortoise as a temporary tool to store some files so I am using it as one machine installation. I do see an _svn folder as well...so I am guessing that is all i need?'

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is copy the filesytem files of where the actual repository is located. Depending on what is serving your subversion repository (Apache or IIS web servers) there should be a configuration file (apache) or setting (iis) that has the path to the repository in it.

for example I have a repository url like:

https://server/svn01p/svn/Repositories/MyStuff/MyProject/branches/December2011

Whatever web server is processing that url will need to know where the actual repository is located so you should be able to work your way back from there.

Answer (score -1):

You don't backup tortoise. You backup the actual repository files, and then you point tortoise to the new location using the "relocate" command in the menu.

Comment: so, basically if I save the directory on a new PC, install Tortoise on the new PC, I should be able to detect the repository? thanks